# Is it possible to set the cookie content with CURL?

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have been searching for a way, to specify the cookie data for CURL. I have found some solutions on how to save the cookies from a visited page, but that's not what I need. What I want is, to write the data for the cookie myself, so CURL uses it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You really should [read the documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) - it's listed with exactly the keywords you'd expect and contains a lot of helpful info:

> -b, --cookie
>
> (HTTP) Pass the data to the HTTP server as a cookie. It is supposedly
>   the data previously received from the server in a "Set-Cookie:" line.
>   The data should be in the format "NAME1=VALUE1; NAME2=VALUE2".
>
> If no '=' symbol is used in the line, it is treated as a filename to
>   use to read previously stored cookie lines from, which should be used
>   in this session if they match. Using this method also activates the
>   "cookie parser" which will make curl record incoming cookies too,
>   which may be handy if you're using this in combination with the -L,
>   --location option. The file format of the file to read cookies from should be plain HTTP headers or the Netscape/Mozilla cookie file
>   format.
>
> NOTE that the file specified with -b, --cookie is only used as input.
>   No cookies will be stored in the file. To store cookies, use the -c,
>   --cookie-jar option or you could even save the HTTP headers to a file using -D, --dump-header!
>
> If this option is set more than once, the last one will be the one
>   that's used.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I wasn't the only one :)

Comment: Works like a charm !

Answer (score 22):

You can use [`curl_setopt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) with the CURLOPT_COOKIE constant:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// cookies to be sent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "fruit=apple; colour=red");
```

Answer (score 2):

cURL can use a cookie file in [Netscape format](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5). Just create such a file yourself and use as the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option.