# Get page content with session authentication

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I looked through Stack Overflow for similar questions but found only pieces of information. So my problem is this:

I want to grab the content of a page let's say : *needpage.php* (using `file_get_contents() + stream_context_create()` or using `cURL()` ) but the page that I need redirects me to a login page ( *loginpage.php* - `<form action=*processlogin.php*>` with user and pass).

Do I need to `cURL()` or `file_get_contents()` the *processlogin.php* page first to `POST` the username and password field, then grab the sessionID and then send another request to the *needpage.php* I need posting:

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'
    )
);
```

What do you think is the right flow? Is it possible that `cURL` or `file_get_contents` to store the `cookie` and then use that cookie for another page?

Comment: I think the solution would be to curl the login page with some posts data (I would need the html code from the login page to tell you exactly) to log-on, then curl the target page.

Comment: It's a simple `<form action='processlogin.php'> <input user> <input pass> </form>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570341/is-it-possible-to-set-the-cookie-content-with-curl

Comment: but how and where it grabs the cookie ? how can I access that cookie ...

Comment: You need a browser library that is session-aware; try [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte). Don't forget to check "robots.txt", and rate-limit your hits on any single IP address. Be willing to be blocked too, as any site operator has the right to do - so don't balance your whole enterprise on the scraping of a single site.

Comment: I need one page, and I don;t think I need browser library. I need cURL or file_get_contents ... and I asked if it is possible for cURL or file_get_contents to store a cookie and then retransmite it to another page on the same domain. Thanks for your answer

Comment: curl allows you to store cookies and will maintain the session until you call curl_close. Just post the necessary fields to the login form's action and then fetch the real page.

Comment: To login, curl processlogin.php with the right post datas (user and pass). Then, send a new curl to the page you want to access BEFORE closing the curl session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) lists all kind of useful flags.  Maybe `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` would help in your case? The documentation seems to claim so unless I misread it well.

If it doesn’t work, there is `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, which can be used to save cookie data to a file, after `curl_close()` has been called.

Then it can be loaded using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.