# PHP CURL | Header Set-Cookie

Tags: php, caching, cookies, curl

I send a request to the server ( asterisk rawman ) using php curl, here is server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Asterisk/11.9.0
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 09:36:51 GMT
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 55
Content-type: text/plain
Cache-Control: no-cache;
Set-Cookie: mansession_id="383b2ccc"; Version=1; Max-Age=60
Pragma: SuppressEvents
```

here the server set a cookie on client system: `Set-Cookie: mansession_id=383b2ccc`.

In the next request i have to send this cookie for pass the authentication... But i don't know where is this cookie ? and how i can send that ?
In the browser its work because browser send the cookie automatically, but in PHP CURL i have a problem

Comment: Manual says use curl_setopt with the CURLOPT_COOKIE option. See http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: You will also find an example by vvondra here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570341/is-it-possible-to-set-the-cookie-content-with-curl

Answer (score 2):

Adapting [vvondra's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10570363/1686492) to your case you would get something like:

You can use curl_setopt with the CURLOPT_COOKIE constant:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// cookies to be sent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "mansession_id=383b2ccc");
```

More in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: ok, but i don't want to set the value manualy, i want to read the cookie value for each login request, because the value change dynamicaly for each request.
in fact i want to find this cookie and read the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to just enable the "cookie engine" in the curl handle, and if you want the cookies to actually get saved somewhere when you're done with the handle you instead use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.

Comment: Ok, I'm Done. i use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to save cookie and read it. thank you all.