# get xml of gestis database

Tags: php, xml, curl

i try to get the (not xml aparently) content of this website:
http://gestis.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_de/010520.xml?f=templates$fn=default-doc.htm$3.0
via curl or file_get_contents in php.

you can open the website in any browser but whenever i try to open it with php to get the content automated it will return a 500 error.

here is the code used:

```
<?php

/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('http://gestis.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_de/010520.xml?f=templates$fn=default-doc.htm$3.0');

echo $returned_content;

?>
```

does anybody have an idea how to get the xml via php from this website?

Comment: Why do you have two curl init calls, one wrapped in a function and one not wrapped in a function that is unused. Further, the link you provided gave me `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`, not an XML resource.

Comment: ah i forgto to write that.
it only gives you content if you open it first via that link:
http://gestis.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll?f=id$t=default-doc.htm$vid=gestisdeu:sdbdeu$id=010520

Comment: But that's not an XML file, either...

Comment: but shouldt than curl get any contents anyways?

Comment: Probably not. Remember how I had to click on a link in order to get to the page that you want? Yea. You'd have to mimic that with cURL. There are probably safeguards in place to deter you from scraping their data.

Comment: Hello i have idea for get response HTML of GESTIS database page. We can use "IFRAME" code to get HTML then we can get value from response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you want to open needs the `vid=gestisdeu:sdbdeu` value in form of a cookie to work:

```
Cookie: nxt/gateway.dll/vid=gestisdeu%3Asdbdeu;
```

Please consult the curl documentation how you can set cookies or take a look into the existing material that is already on this webiste, for example [Is it possible to set the cookie content with CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10570341/367456) and the like.

Take care that depending on website and their configuration changes this might become different. So technically your question can't be really answered, because that website doesn't have any documentation of it's HTTP request requirements. So you need to find out on your own and provide those if you ask such a question.

PHP Example:

```
$url = 'http://gestis.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_de/010520.xml?f=templates$fn=default-doc.htm$3.0';
$options['http'] = ['header' => 'Cookie: nxt/gateway.dll/vid=gestisdeu%3Asdbdeu;'];
stream_context_set_default($options);
$content = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($content);
```

Output:

```
string(104975) "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>DGUV-IFA GESTIS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_de/010520.xml?f=stylesheets$fn=gestis-doc.css$up=1$3.0" type="text/css">
<"...
```