# PHP: How to send cookies with REST API call by clicking on a link?

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, cookies

I'm new to the REST APIs style of web development. I have to send 2 cookies along with 1 REST API. How do I send them together by clicking on a link?

For example, if an user clicks on the link, it is supposed to make the REST API call and send the cookie along with it. I know how to do it in the cURL but I am confused as to how I can trigger that via a link. Ideally, the user should be able to download a zip file by clicking the link. The link should call the REST API and send 2 cookies over to get the zip file. I am able to get the raw code of the zip file using the following code but is not able to achieve that by clicking on the link.

```
    $getResultsDetails = curl_init();
    $getResults_service_url = '<URL of the REST API call>';
    curl_setopt($getResultsDetails,CURLOPT_URL,$getResults_service_url);
    curl_setopt($getResultsDetails,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=".$LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY.";QCSession=".$QCSession);
        curl_setopt($getResultsDetails, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //get response
        $getResults_service_url_response = curl_exec($getResultsDetails);
        curl_setopt($getResultsDetails, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        if ($getResults_service_url_response === false) {
            $info = curl_getinfo($getResultsDetails);
            curl_close($getResultsDetails);
            die('error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
        }
        curl_close($getResultsDetails);
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570341/is-it-possible-to-set-the-cookie-content-with-curl) but with the added 'how do I?' part. So, heres the bit to add to the answer of that question.

just use a link to direct your user to the php script making the call.

you can do this in 2 ways:

**1.**

```
<a href="yourCurlScript.php">click me</a>
```

read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570341/is-it-possible-to-set-the-cookie-content-with-curl) for details on how to do the cookie part.

or

**2.** use an ajax call using jquery:

[from jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "path/to/yourCurlScript.php",
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

same script is called, so process cookies in the same way.

for the best user experience I would probably opt for number 2.  I dont know what it is that youre planning on retrieving from the API, but you can pipe it into a file using either.